# Want to use journaling enabled DB in 32 bit system-MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, bit, journaling

I want to run an existing application, that was developed earlier on `64 bit` machine.
It already has an existing database **mongoDB** with journaling enabled for 64 bit.

In `32 bit` system journaling is not enabled, so when I try to run MongoDB service with this DB, it does not work

How can i reuse this DB and able to run this application in my `32 bit` system?

Comment: What is the error that you get when you try to run MongoDB with the 64-bit database? Have you trie using mongodump and mongorestore to transfer the data?

Answer (score 4):

You can manually enable journaling in 32bit MongoDB by starting `mongod` with the command line parameter `--journal`.

When it still doesn't work, you can use the [mongodump](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongodump/) utility on the 64bit database to export your database to a file. Then you can use [mongorestore](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongorestore/) to import it into your 32bit database.

However, keep in mind that MongoDB has severe limitations in 32bit mode, the most critical one being that your total database size is restricted to about 2GB of data, even less when you have journaling enabled (you can reduce the impact of journaling a bit with the additional parameter `--smallfile`). When your database is larger than this, it will not work on a 32bit system.