# Enable journaling in mongoDB(2.6.5) on Ubuntu 12.04 - 32 bit

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu-12.04, 32-bit

I want to run mongoDB with journaling enabled on my ubuntu system.To enable journaling i am starting mongoDB with following command:

```
          mongod --port 27017 --dbpath /data/db --journal
```

This gives me temporary journaling enabled and when i close the terminal, mongoDB goes down.
Then i tried to restart mongoDB removing lock file but it fails. I,then,removed all the files from data directory and succeeded to start the db but with no past data.
I have done a lot of research to find out the reason(e.g.[Want to use journaling enabled DB in 32 bit system-MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26922914/want-to-use-journaling-enabled-db-in-32-bit-system-mongodb)) but did not get satisfactory answer.Any explanation will be of great help.

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is, exactly. Do you have an error message you can post? You shouldn't remove the lock file, and the past data disappeared because you deleted it. Finally, why are you using 32-bit? There are large limitations of MongoDB on 32-bit systems.

Comment: one can not re-start mongo untill lock file is present.In error message it was saying something like "could not start mongodb" but now m not having the past logs. I am using 32 bit because my system is 32 bit.I was wondering why there are so many limitations for 32bit on mongo as MySQL is exceptionally wonderful with no such issues.

Comment: The reason for the limitations is the limit on addressable memory in 32-bit systems, because MongoDB (as of 2.6) uses memory-mapped files for the storage engine. If you are forced to use 32-bit systems, I would advise against using MongoDB (in production).